# can't connect to local host python

Tags: python, sockets

Hi i made this file server app and i opened the server in one laptop, and opened the client program in another laptop but i couldn't connect to the server. both laptops are connected to same wifi so shouldn't it be working? and if i open the server and client program in one laptop, the client can connect to server.

here's my code

Server

```
import threading
import os
import socket

def RetrFile(name, sock):
    filename = str(sock.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
    print(filename)
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        sock.send(bytes("EXISTS" + str(os.path.getsize(filename)), 'utf-8'))
        userResponse = str(sock.recv(1024), 'utf-8')
        if userResponse[:2] == 'Ok':
            with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
                bytesToSend = f.read(1024)
                sock.send(bytesToSend)
                while bytesToSend != "":
                    bytesToSend=f.read(1024)
                    sock.send(bytesToSend)
    else:
        sock.send(bytes("ERR", 'utf-8'))
    sock.close()

def Main():
    host = socket.gethostbyname("localhost")
    port = 5123
    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind(('0.0.0.0', port))
    s.listen(5)
    print("Server started")
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Client connected" + str(addr))
        t = threading.Thread(target=RetrFile, args=("rthread", c))
        t.start()
    s.close()

Main()
```

Client

```
import socket

def Main():
    host = socket.gethostbyname("localhost")
    port = 5123

    s= socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    filename = input("Filename? ->")
    if filename != 'q':
        s.send(bytes(filename,'utf-8'))
        data=str(s.recv(1024),'utf-8')
        if data[:6] == 'EXISTS':
            filesze = data[6:]
            message = input("File Exists" + filesze + "(Y/N)")

            if message == 'Y':
                s.send(bytes("Ok",'utf-8'))
                f = open('new_'+filename, 'wb')
                data = s.recv(1024)
                total = len(data)
                f.write(data)
                while total < int(filesze):
                    data = s.recv(1024)
                    total+= len(data)
                    f.write(data)
                    print('%.2f' %((total/int(filesze)*100)), " percentage complted ")
                print("Download Complete")
        else:
            print("doesnt exist")

    s.close()
Main()
```

Comment: Can you connect using `telnet other-host 5123`? Do you have a firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding the meaning of "localhost". It always, only refers to the exact computer you're on. So for the client, "localhost" resolves to itself, and on the server "localhost" refers to itself. Hence, the client looks for the server running on its own computer at port 5123, which of course fails because the server isn't running on its same computer, it's running somewhere else. That's also why the code works when the server and the client are both on the same machine.

You need to get the ip address or hostname of the server laptop in order to connect to it from the client. You can get this by running `hostname` on the server computer in a linux terminal or windows command line, and putting that name instead of `"localhost"` into the code that's running on the client computer.

E.g., on the server laptop in a terminal:

```
$ hostname
myserver
```

And in your client code:

```
host = socket.gethostbyname("myserver")
```

Comment: how can i do with window 10?

Comment: Edited the post about this. `hostname` is available in Windows command prompt as well (hit `windows key + R` to get to the "Run" windows, then type `cmd` and hit Enter to get to command prompt)

Comment: when i do hostname on command line, i get the name of my laptop. is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You need the client to refer to the server laptop either by name or by IP address. Since they're on the same local network, you should be fine just using its name

Comment: Using the server's host name may not work. It depends on whether the two machines share a naming protocol such as DNS, MDNS, etc... If the name doesn't work, you can fall back to the IP address.

Comment: oh thanks it works. but one more question. if i change the wifi will it work the same? for example if my two laptops use my hotspot